# Continuous migration

Tags: 7, drush, migrations

I would like to know what is the best way to achieve a continuous migration from external DB (via [Migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate)).

Basically, there are several migration classes that need to be to repeatedly migrated in an ordered way (the external DB is also updated).
This said, exception management is welcomed/required during the run.

I was trying to find a solution for this but found nothing concrete.
From gathered information some approaches are to use Jenkins/Drush combination, but I wonder if adding Jenkins would be an overkill in my case.

Is there a good way to achieve this via Drush only?

Thanks

Comment: Please avoid questions like "best way" - this is opinion based to the point of loosing usefulness. Also, it's quite impossible to tell if something is overkill in your case, because it's hardly possible to fit your case in enough detail into a Q&A question.

Answer (score 0):

Set up a script to call drush at regular intervals. There are several drush commands to manage migrations, such as `drush migrate-status`.